# Nginx not serving application to the internet

Tags: node.js, nginx

My Nginx and Node.js application is not serving my application to the internet. When I try to access `http://helloworld.example.com` in my browser it cannot connecf.

Here is my helloworld.conf file:

```
upstream backend {
        server localhost:8000;
        keepalive 32;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name helloworld.example.com;

        location / {
                client_max_body_size 50M;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
}
```

Here is my Node app:

```
var http = require('http'); 

var hostname = 'localhost';
var port = 8000;

var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.end('Hello World!');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
        console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}`);
});
```

And heres my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Node.js Application
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/root
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node usr/bin/helloworld.js

Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service file status shows active and so does the Nginx config file and the node js app run perfectly. Any help?

Comment: you do not describe what exactly is not working.

Comment: I don't know how it isn't working

Comment: what are you trying, what does not work? are you trying to open `http://helloworld.example.com` in your browser and that shows an error? if so, what kind of error?

Comment: Yes I am trying to go the that url and it says "this site cannot be reached"

Comment: Are you aware that example.com is a, well, example domain, used as a placeholder but cannot actually be used? Or did you add it to hide the real server name?

Comment: I followed a tutorial that had that and it worked for them

Comment: https://blog.eduonix.com/web-programming-tutorials/deploy-node-js-application-linux-server/

Comment: Also I turned the URL into a bunch or random characters and it still didn't work

Comment: ok, it seems that tutorial got something wrong. why do you need the nginx? can you just use http://localhost:8000 alternatively?

Comment: yes, I can but I am trying to host a domain from home. I'm new at this sort of thing and I have no idea if this is the right path to take

Comment: in that case you should reformulate your question to reflect that.

Comment: I don't know if it was you since i didn't look at the name but I accepted a change someone sent me so thank you if it was you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following configuration, it's from my `NGINX` server and works fine

```
server{

    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Host               $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }
}
```

It listens on port `80` of `localhost` and for every request it receives, it forwards it to `http://localhost:8000`.

Not specifying anything except `proxy_pass` will work too

You can learn more about the directives below `proxy_pass` from the docs [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/)

To connect the application to the internet you just have to change the `server_name` property in then config assuming that you domain points correctly to your server.

Changing `server_name localhost` to `server_name helloworld.example.com` will make the application available on the internet.

Comment: note that the question is about serving the application to the internet, so this does not really answer that.

Comment: @criztovyl I've updated the answer accordingly

Comment: well, your added statement is not true, simply changing server_name does not make it availale in the internet. :)

Answer (score 1):

To expose your application to the Internet, to host it from home, you need to  make changes to systems outside your local machine.

In a typical setup your local computer is not connected to the internet directly. Instead it goes via a router, which is directly connected to the internet.

To the internet you appear with the address of your router and the internet can address your router by it's address. Normally your router "only" forwards your requests to the internet and accepts the responses. (The technical term here is NAT.) But it does not accept any incoming requests, because the router does not know how to handle the request. (Technically the router also blocks the request because it's Firewall is configured reject request.)

```
  +------------+                    +-------------+
  | your local |<--- WiFi / LAN ----| your router |<---- the internet
  |   machine  |----            --->|             |----->
  +------------+                    +-------------+
```

To make your application available to the internet you will need to tell the router to forward request to your local machine. How this is done depends on your Router, but the keyword here is Port Forwarding.

To forward a port you need to specify the port and the protocol to forward, in case of http this is port 80 (from the `listen 80`) and protocol TCP (the protocol http uses under the hood). Most routers automatically open this port in the Firewall, but for others you have to explicitly configure it. You most likely also have to open the port 80 in the firewall of your *local* machine, so the forwarding request is not rejected by your local machine.

If you have set up this forwarding other can now access your application via your routers (IP) address, for example `http://91.11.84.87`, but not via a domain name (yet).

To get a domain name you typically need to buy/rent (register) a domain name from a domain registrar and "attach" your routers address to the domain. (The keyword being DNS.) Getting a domain name is a story of it's own.

Typically your routers IP address changes regularly, so you will need to also update that address for your domain then! If you are in luck your registrar and router both support DynDNS: This way your router automatically updates the address with your registrar.

I hope this helps you into the right directions.